# Grouping and generating an array of arrays with Google SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I was using Google SQL and I ran into the following challenge. For practical issues, let's assume we have the following table:

**TABLE_1**

| Status (string) | Values (array) |
| --- | --- |
| Status 1 | `[a,b]` |
| Status 1 | `[c,d]` |
| Status 1 | `[e,f]` |
| Status 2 | `[g,h]` |
| Status 2 | `[i,j]` |

And the desired outcome is the table_2, which should be structured as follows:

**TABLE_2**

| Status (string) | Values (array of arrays) |
| --- | --- |
| Status 1 | `[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]` |
| Status 2 | `[[g,h],[i,j]]` |

I have tried using array grouping functions but I didn't manage to get SQL to build arrays of arrays in the process of grouping by status. What am I missing?

Comment: Nested arrays are not supported in BigQuery. So, you need to revisit your expected output

Comment: Noted, thanks Mikhail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Mikhail, this is not possible with BigQuery, so I am closing this thread.